# Build Stability Plugin for Sonar does not gather data from Jenkins / Hudson CI server

Tags: hudson, jenkins, sonarqube

I want to monitor the build stability of my continuous integration builds. To do that, I am using the [Build Stability Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Stability+Plugin) for Sonar, but unfortunately, I was not able to make it work correctly.

At the end of the build (basically a `mvn clean install sonar:sonar`), the logs display the following information:

```
[INFO]  Sensor org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.BuildStabilitySensor@13fc816...
[INFO]  CI URL: http://localhost:8080/jenkins
[WARN]  Unknown CiManagement system or incorrect URL: http://localhost:8080/jenkins
[INFO]  Sensor org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.BuildStabilitySensor@13fc816 done: 47 ms
```

On Sonar, the widget does not display any data...

Of course, the URL is correct, and both Jenkins and Sonar are running correctly, and on the same machine. Did I miss something?

I am currently working with Jenkins 1.410, Sonar 2.7 and plugin 1.1.2, but I also tried with an older installation (Hudson 1.347 and Sonar 2.1.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the problem (thanks the code browsing ;) ).

I set the URL for my build to `http://localhost:8080/jenkins`, but the correct URL is `Hudson:http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/MyJobName`.

But unfortunately, this plugin does not meet my requirements, but this is another problem!